# How to make the device connect to wifi after scan the QR for enrolling android device in Android Management API?

Tags: android, wifi, emm

I used to enroll an android device by DPC method.
Now I am trying to switch to Android Management API method however I can't manage to make the device auto connect to WiFi after scan the QR code.

I am trying to configure wifi network as below but not work, after scan QR code it still ask me to connect to wifi network manually

```
"openNetworkConfiguration": {
"NetworkConfigurations": [
  {
    "Type": "WiFi",
    "GUID": "a0989e28-9c23-43e5-b5d3-9b37d86723a3",
    "WiFi": {
      "AutoConnect": true,
      "Passphrase": "YYY",
      "Security": "WPA-PSK",
      "SSID": "XXX"
    },
    "Name": "ABC"
  }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Android can directly connect to wifi during 6-tap provisioning if it is able to find EXTRA PROVISIONING values in QR code config.

In the QR Code config add:

- SSID of the wifi with this key [EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID)
- Wifi password with this Key [EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD)
- Wifi Security type with this Key [EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SECURITY_TYPE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SECURITY_TYPE)

With these values in QR code, android will be directly able to identify wifi and connect to it automatically.